# Manually doing what bitaddress.org does

Tags: paper-wallet, coldstorage

I want to create a paper wallet but want to do it manually.  I understand that bitaddress.org automates the process for you.

Do instructions exist which I can follow to do the same thing which bitaddress does to create a paper wallet?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually'?

Comment: Like user a spreadsheet to manually generate the keys, or maybe by using the terminal in Linux?

Comment: You still need a program that generates the keys for you...

Comment: can the keys not be generated using sha256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your familiar with javascript then I think the easiest way to go would be to check out https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib . They offer a client side solution for generating bitcoin address info.  Theres a few examples in the readme as well.